# How do I unload a library after completing a task?

Tags: php, codeigniter

After completing a task I need to unload a library because it is disturbing other variables and functions.

Comment: That's a statement. Did you mean to ask "How do I unload a library after completing a task?"

Comment: I find it unlikely the library is the cause of your problem; especially if it's a native CI one.

Comment: library being an external `php` file, or a `.so` or `.dll` library loaded via `dl()`? Either way, you can't, as a library may install hooks and initialize memory that it wouldnt be ablt to restore cleanly un an unload

Comment: I got the solution i use unset($this->library); it is working

Answer (score 0):

Probably by using $this->libname = null; ? Just a guess. But your problem shouldn't occur in the first place, so I suggest you check your code.